# How to add the two values from different columns in SQL

Tags: query

I have the following data below:

```
column 1 | column 2 
23       | 25
```

I would like query the data in such a was as to have the following results:

```
column 1 | column 2 | total 
23       | 25       | (column 1 + column 2)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `SUM(val1+val2) AS Total`
(?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT val1 + val2 AS sum FROM table
```

If you will select the two original columns and the sum:

```
SELECT val1, val2, val1 + val2 AS sum FROM table
```